# Joomla - pagination bar not showing up

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla3.0

I'm trying to get pagination working in my joompla component admin page (table of records from database).

I'm using the standard method found on the net, so in my view class I have:

```
function display($tmpl=NULL)
{

    $this->tabela = $this->get('Items');

    $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');

    $this->state = $this->get('State');
...
```

and then in my default template for this view:

```
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" >
                <?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

but the pagination is not showing up. In the place where it should occur I can only see this (in website's HTML):

```
<div class="pagination pagination-toolbar">
<input type="hidden" name="limitstart" value="0">
</div>
```

How can I get this pagination work?

Comment: it will showing if your number of rows are more than defined value for "Default List Limit"

Comment: Where can I set this value?

Comment: in joomla global configuration